# PJSIP (compile with TLS) error while make

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, pjsip

I am trying to compile the pjsip libraries for iPhone (with TLS support). The Open SSL is compiled successfully, and that is verified by the configure script. 
I can also successfully compile. make dep. But when I try 'make', I get the following error:
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `libpjsua2-arm-apple-darwin9.a', needed by`../bin/pjsua2-test-arm-apple-darwin9'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [pjsua2-test-arm-apple-darwin9] Error 2

It would be of great help if I could have some clue as to how to resolve this error.